# Call state in nested view ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to call a state in my nested view, but I get the error:

`Could not resolve 'category' from state 'project'`

I got a state called `project` with a nested view of `categories@project`.
The view is just loading fine, but when I try to go to another state (not in the project state) I get this error.

So the states are as follow.

- project

  - categories@project
- category

So I want to go to the `category` state in the `categories@project` nested view.
How is this possible?

Now I only have `ui-sref="category"`, but that's throwing the error..

**UPDATE: Added code snippet of my routing file with the `project` and `category.create` state.**

```
.state('project', {
   url: '/project/:projectId',
   resolve: {
      project: function (Project, $stateParams) {
         return Project.get({projectId: $stateParams.projectId}).$promise;
      }
   },
   views: {
      '': {
         templateUrl: 'views/project/project.html',
         controller: 'ProjectCtrl'
      },
      'info@project': {
         templateUrl: 'views/project/nested/info.html'
      },
      'contacts@project': {
         templateUrl: 'views/project/nested/contacts.html'
      },
      'todos@project': {
         templateUrl: 'views/project/nested/todos.html'
      },
      'categories@project': {
         templateUrl: 'views/project/nested/categories.html'
      }
   }
})
.state('category.create', {
   url: '/project/:projectId/category',
   templateUrl: 'views/category/create.html',
   controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
})
```

Btw, when I rename my `category.create` state to `category`, it throws an uknown object error..

Comment: May I see a code snippet of your routing file? It would really help.

Comment: @VerronKnowles I've updated it

Comment: Unless all the code for your routing isn't present, you have not defined a category state. ui-sref points to the name you gave the state. i.e. .state('<name given to state>', <state code>). Do you have a page for viewing individual categories?

Comment: @VerronKnowles Yes I have.

Comment: I see category.create, but not category. Is this not all of the code?

Comment: @VerronKnowles I have not category. Cause I only have a view in my project where I list my categories. So I only created category.create and category.edit, but that isn't the right way I guess..

Comment: Gotcha. To the extend of my knowledge, I do not believe ui-sref will work with categories@project. I believe you'll have to actually make a category view if you want ui-sref to go to it. Just make a catagory state pointing to a categories.html file you would like to view.